# Feasibility of Psycho Pass' Dominator

Tags: science-based, internal-consistency, weapons

So, in the world of Psycho Pass, the main weapon of enforcement is the Dominator.[image]

There is not much information on how the weapon works, other than it utilises electromagnetic waves, and has an ID scanning system for the agents in the series to access the weapon.

I understand that the Lethal Eliminator Function is certainly absurd and unfeasible, especially by electromagnetic waves, since people cannot bloat up so easily and explode. However, the Non-Lethal Paralyser (which merely stuns people) and Destroy Decomposer functions (which disintegrates objects) do seem more likely to be replicated.

So, aside from the ID scan system, how can the Non-Lethal Paralyzer and Destroy Decomposer function be replicated? It need not be from EM waves, but from any type of laser, particle beam or wave.

Comment: Destroy Decomposer is even worse. Much like any other disintegration, it'd result in a huge explosion since you're turning a big chunk of solid material into hot gas under a second. Wouldn't want to be near when it happens.

Comment: Oh yes. Thanks for pointing it out. Maybe just melt and a smaller area if necessary. Or there are good body armour to make up.

Answer (score 2):

The Dominator is an EM gun right, and If I am not wrong, the neurological system of a human body is based on electricity running through millions on neurons.

So, Assuming that the Dominator can produce precise enough EM waves around the body, such that it distorts the neurological electrical signal, and I am handwaving this part, you can achieve your desired results quite easily.

You want someone to stop moving, simply point it to them on paralysis settings and the muscles stop receiving signals going into uncontrolled disarray, similar to a taser gun these days. While on the lethal setting this gun can actually fry the neurons inside the brain, causing immediate death.

Answer (score 2):

Not being familiar with the production in question, I had a look for some videos of the effects. I found "[Destroy Decomposer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=citLnLO9FDA)", but not "Non-Lethal Paralyser". If anyone had a nice *short* video clip of the latter, I might update my answer. Maybe.

---

As Mephistopheles observed in the comments, Destroy Decomposer is basically impractical, because there is no way to promptly reduce an object to gas or dust that doesn't involve deliverying an *awful* lot of energy to it, and doing that is going to generate a significant explosion. The shooter in the linked clip above would be blasted back, and probably be dead even before they hit the scenery which would *guarantee* it.

Furthermore, delivering enough energy to explode an object of that size via EM radiation is probably impractical from a gun of that size; the power density of the gun would probably exceed the capacity of any practical material to withstand without melting, and the energy density of the power source would be closer to "nuclear weapon" than "battery pack". You'd probably have to shoot some kind of explosive projectile, probably with some kind of nuclear warhead (perhaps antimatter-catalysed). I'm sure you get the idea about how silly this would be. The lesson here is that if you want to stop something as big and bad as a tank, and you want to stop it quickly, then bring some antitank weaponry with you and don't try and use your handgun.

---

Not knowing the exact effects of the non-lethal mode, it is hard to say exactly what could be done.

The real-life [Active Denial System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_Denial_System) uses 95GHz microwaves to cause skin surface heating... it won't paralyse anyone, but it is quite hard to kill them and they'll definitely want the effect to stop promptly (probably via the medium of "running away").

A perhaps more suitable design is the [electrolaser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrolaser). You need a couple of laser pulses to ionise two paths through the air between the gun and the target, and then you run a suitably modulated electrical current through them, zapping the target. This could have an effect very similar to that of a [taser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taser), only with a handful of important differences such as effectively zero flight time, dart drop or separation, but also no continuous electrical connection due to the lack of barbed darts so it could knock someone off their feet but wouldn't necessarily keep them on the floor afterwards. It is conceivable that the right kind of electrical signal delivered to the right bits of the body could cause longer lasting paralytic effects or short term [unconsciousness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syncope_(medicine)), but anything that can jangle the brain that badly has a good chance of causing serious long term effects or even death. Hell, *tasers* [can kill people,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taser_safety_issues#Deaths_and_injuries_related_to_Taser_use) and they're not nearly as hazardous as the sort of weapon you're after!

Such a weapon could also be dialled up to kill (by inducing [fibrillation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibrillation)) or blind if you shot someone in the face (possibly reversibly, depending on the choice of laser wavelength... frazzles corneas are easier to replace than scorched retinas). They could also work on electrical equipment, such as car ignitions and engine control units, as well as more exotic equipment like robots. They would not, alas, be able to disintegrate stuff more substantial than cotton wool.